# Cannot figure out what simple thing I am doing wrong with this CoreData object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, boolean

I have a CoreData object called "User".  This object has a property declared with `@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * isloggedin;` in User.h and in User.m I have `@dynamic isloggedin;`
In my AppDelegate I have this method:

```
- (NSManagedObject *) getLoggedInUserFromCurrentServer {
NSManagedObject *theUser = nil;

    for (User *user in [[self myServer] users]) {
        if (user.isloggedin == [NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]) {
            // we found it
            theUser = user;
            break;
        }
    }

    return theUser;
}
```

I have looked at the table in my database and there is only a single user and only a single server.  That user has `ZISLOGGEDIN` set to 1.
When this code goes through, the `IF` statement says false.
`[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]` returns 1 if I `po` it.
If I `po user.isloggedin` or `po [user isloggedin]` I get `no member named isloggedin` and `Target does not respond to this message selector`.
I had this code working before, but changed it and cannot figure out what I did before that made this work...or for that sake, why this won't work.  I'm sure I'm missing some insanely obvious thing here...but I can't find it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: `NSNumber` is a pointer type and so by using `==` to compare, you're actually comparing pointers to distinct `NSNumber` objects. Thus, even if both contain the same `BOOL` values, your comparison won't evaluate to `YES`.

To compare their primitive `BOOL` types, use `boolValue`:

```
for (User *user in [[self myServer] users]) {
    if ([user.isloggedin boolValue] == YES) {
        // we found it
        theUser = user;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: BEAUTIFUL!  As you can see, I'm still learning Objective-C.  Thanks!